# JSON array parsing using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

I have following JSON:

```
{
"category": {
    "category_identification": "1",
    "category_name": "C1",
    "image_one": "1.PNG",
    "image_two": "1_.PNG",
    "logo": "LOGO_1.PNG",
    "category_description": "DESCRIPTION"
},
"responseCode": "1"
}
```

I have to check if responseCode is 1 then have to display information from category (category_description, logo, etc.).
I tried following code:

```
              $.each(data1, function(key, value) {
                    if (data1.responseCode == '1') {
                        alert(value.category_name)  
                    }
                });
```

where data1 is a JSON.
I am getting undefined result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just change `value` to `data1.category`? Like this:

```
$.each(data1, function(key, value) {
    if (data1.responseCode == '1') {
        alert(data1.category.category_name)  
    }
});
```

I wrote this answer because I don't see an array of JSONs, but only one JSON object. If that's the case, we can make it even simpler:

```
if (data1.responseCode == '1') {
    alert(data1.category.category_name)  
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right no need of each. I used your login but still getting undefined result.

Comment: @Little tilli Is there any chance that you are missing `data1 = JSON.parse(data1)` before your code?

Comment: Actually I am fetching JSON from ajax.

Comment: @Littletilli but you have to use `JSON.parse()`, because even from AJAX you are returning plain text, not an object, so you have to parse it.

Comment: So I suppose data1 is a string. You should convert it to object through JSON.parse().

Comment: here is my code :    $.getJSON(value.URL + "/getCategory", {category_identification : catID}, function(data1) {
     if (data1.responseCode == '1') {
         alert(data1.category.category_name)  
     }
    });

Comment: After adding     data1 = JSON.parse(data1) I get:    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o